# Why max-width: 100% will create fluid images when applied to the <img> element?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

From my point of view, it's just the "max" width, so why it will create fluid images and take full space to its' container?

Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time the images are larger than the max-width, if they were smaller, it wouldn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

It will not make the image "take full space to it's container" - it just won't allow the img element to be any wider than it's container.

If the image's native size is larger than it's container, then it will be the full width. If it's native size is smaller than it's container, then `max-width:100%` will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just rendering at its native width and overflowing its containing box, the image would render at its native dimensions as long as its width didn’t exceed the width of its container.

Answer (score 0):

The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of an element.

```
max-width: none;
```

(default)   No maximum width.

```
max-width: 100px;
```

Defines the maximum width in px, cm, etc. (This is what you think)

```
max-width: 80%;
```

Defines the **maximum width in percent of the containing block**

```
max-width: initial;
```

Sets this property to its default value.

```
max-width: inherit;
```

Inherits this property from its parent element.